# [Quartz]how can I add jobs into one Scheduler of quartz dynamically？

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I started a Scheduler for a while,then i add new job into this Scheduler and find that this new job will execute immediately because the start time of this job is the same as Scheduler. If I just want the job come into effect the time I add it into Scheduler, how can I do? thx!!!!!
this is the code :

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
    JobDetail job = newJob(InvokeStatJob.class)             //print "hello -- "+ new Date()
            .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .build();
    CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/2 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
    JobDetail job2 = newJob(InvokeStatJob2.class)           //print "world! --- "+new Date()
            .withIdentity("job2", "group2")
            .build();
    CronTrigger trigger2 = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger2", "group2")
            .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/3 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
    sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    sched.start();
    Thread.sleep(10L * 1000L);
    System.out.println("=========================");
    sched.scheduleJob(job2,trigger2);
    Thread.sleep(30L*1000L);
    sched.shutdown(true);
```

this is the results:

```
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:18 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:20 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:22 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:24 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:26 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:28 CST 2015
=========================
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:28 CST 2015
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:28 CST 2015
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:28 CST 2015
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:28 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:30 CST 2015
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:30 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:32 CST 2015
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:33 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:34 CST 2015
hello -- Mon Dec 28 10:33:36 CST 2015
world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:36 CST 2015
```

the first 4 "world! --- Mon Dec 28 10:33:28 CST 2015" after "=========================" is not my want.

Comment: Question is not clear. You want to add jobs after starting scheduler?

Comment: yes，i update the description

Comment: You scheduled it after printing ===================. That is why it is running after that.The scheduling will be in effect only after we start it using method `scheduleJob`.

Answer (score 0):

from [Quartz Scheduler Developer Guide : Working with Triggers : Triggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fco-trg_about_triggers.html%23)

> The startTime property indicates when the trigger's schedule first comes into effect. The value is a java.util.Date object that defines a moment in time on a given calendar date. For some trigger types, the trigger will actually fire at the start time. For others it simply marks the time that the schedule should start being followed. This means you can store a trigger with a schedule such as “every 5th day of the month” during January, and if the startTime property is set to April 1st, it will be a few months before the first firing.

the code should be:

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
    JobDetail job = newJob(InvokeStatJob.class)             //print "hello -- "+ new Date()
            .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .build();
    CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/2 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
    sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    sched.start();
    Thread.sleep(10L * 1000L);
    System.out.println("=========================");
    JobDetail job2 = newJob(InvokeStatJob2.class)           //print "world! --- "+new Date()
            .withIdentity("job2", "group2")
            .build();
    CronTrigger trigger2 = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("trigger2", "group2")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/3 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
    sched.scheduleJob(job2, trigger2);
    Thread.sleep(30L*1000L);
    sched.shutdown(true);
```